# Wrong links for subsections in appendix

Tags: appendices, links, article

I noticed a subtle problem while writing an appendix. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\let\chapter\section
\begin{document}
\section{One}
ASD
\subsection{One.one}
qwe
\subsubsection{One.one.one}
asda123
\subsection{One.two}
zxc
\newpage
\appendix
\section{A}
\subsection{A.one}
\subsection{A.two}
\subsection{A.three}
\end{document}
```

The problem happens with the links of the `subsection` and `subsubsection` of the appendix, when there is an equivalent chapter in the main matter. In the example, the error happens with subsections A.1 and A.2, which lead to subsections 1.1 and 1.2. The link to subsection A.3, however, works correctly.

Why does it happen? Is there a quick fix for this error? (I wouldn't want to add a new package or change my whole document just to fix this problem).

Comment: Why do you `\let\chapter\section`? I strongly believe this is causing your troubles.

Comment: Thank you. That was causing the problem. The template I was given says that it can produce some issues with the package `algorithm2e`, but so far it seems to work.

Comment: Note that `hyperref` behaves differently if `\chapter` is defined or not, particularly when appendices are involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\let\chapter\section` is no good idea here -- do not use such setups.

`hyperref` generates wrong anchors from this then.

If it is really needed, defining the relevant `chapter` counter cures the problem. But again: Don't use this!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcounter{chapter}
\let\chapter\section
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{One}
ASD
\subsection{One.one}
qwe
\subsubsection{One.one.one}
asda123
\subsection{One.two}
zxc
\newpage
\appendix
\section{A}
\subsection{A.one}
\subsection{A.two}
\subsection{A.three}
\end{document}
```